# Powershell Format-Table Expression not allowing division of PsCustomObject member

Tags: azure, powershell, formatting

I have the following command that I have been working on for retrieving the total storage capacity used across our storage accounts in Azure. The query gets my results in bytes, but I would like to convert them into Gibibytes (GiB) which is similar to what Azure shows on their UI.

The current script with the offending division expression:

```
     (az storage account list --query "[].{Name:name,ResourceGroup:resourceGroup}" | 
        ConvertFrom-Json) |
        % {$i=0}
            {az monitor metrics list 
                --resource $_[$i].name 
                --resource-type Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts 
                --resource-group $_[$i].resourceGroup 
                --metrics 'UsedCapacity' 
                --interval PT1H 
                --query "{Id:value[].id,ResourceGroup:value[].resourceGroup,UsedCapacity:value[].timeseries[].data[].average}" |
        ConvertFrom-Json} |
        Format-Table 
            @{Label="Resource";Expression={$_.Id.Split("/")[8]}},
            ResourceGroup,
            @{Label="Gibibytes";Expression={If(($_.UsedCapacity -eq null) -or ($_UsedCapacity -eq 0)){0} Else {([int]$_.UsedCapacity/1.074e+9)}}}
```

I have been reading through docs and other SO posts, but have not been able to figure out why my division is returning a blank entry when attempting to divide. I added the conditional to check for 0 and nulls thinking that it was a null value error. When I remove the division, the values come across fine.

**Any idea on why I cannot get the math to work within this expression block?**

Note: I am newer to all of these Powershell functions and may be missing something basic.

Here is the command that does work (without the division)

```
    (az storage account list --query "[].{Name:name,ResourceGroup:resourceGroup}" | ConvertFrom-Json)| % {$i=0}{az monitor metrics list --resource $_[$i].name --resource-type Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts --resource-group $_[$i].resourceGroup --metrics 'UsedCapacity' --interval PT1H --query "{Id:value[].id,ResourceGroup:value[].resourceGroup,UsedCapacity:value[].timeseries[].data[].average}"| ConvertFrom-Json} | Format-Table @{Label="Resource";Expression={$_.Id.Split("/")[8]}},ResourceGroup,@{Label="Gibibytes";Expression={$_.UsedCapacity}};
```

Edit (Sample of the JSON using my query from 'az monitor metrics list'):

```
    {
      "Id": [
        "/subscriptions/16b5877d-2988-4a0d-b207-760d5168ef3d/resourceGroups/{MyResourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{MyStorageAccountName}/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics/UsedCapacity"
      ],
      "ResourceGroup": [
        "{MyResourceGroupName}"
      ],
      "UsedCapacity": [
        1442090.0
      ]
    }
```

Edit 2: Cleaned up the snippet structure

Edit 3: Output of
`(az storage account list --query "[].{Name:name,ResourceGroup:resourceGroup}" )`

```
    [
      {
        "Name": "{storageAccount1}",
        "ResourceGroup": "{resourceGroup1}"
      },
      {
        "Name": "storageAccount2",
        "ResourceGroup": "{resourceGroup1}"
      },
      {
        "Name": "storageAccount3",
        "ResourceGroup": "{resourceGroup2}"
      }
    ]
```

Edit 4: Learned how to syntax highlight...
Edit 5: Added output example -- mostly redacted due to the naming. The only piece not working is the Gibibytes (GiB) output.
[image: Full snippet output with empty GiB]

Edit 5: Thanks everyone -- the response was a json array, so I was referencing the wrong value. The correct code snippet should be:

```
{([int]$_.UsedCapacity[0]/1.074e+9).ToString()+" GiB"}
```

I will look into whether I can modify that query to return a cleaner result, but my immediate search when trying to format the result kept bringing me back to using ConvertFrom-Json in powershell.

Comment: Can you post the raw json response from ```az storage account list ...``` and ```az monitor metrics list ...``` (or a small redacted sample of them). Without seeing the json it's hard to work out what might be going wrong. An example of your incorrect output would be useful, as well as the expected result.

Comment: Please also do not cram it all into one extremely long line of code. Do yourself a favor and write multiline code which will make it readable and much easier to spot mistakes.

Comment: Added snippets of responses. I was hoping to keep this to a single command since it is really just combining two Azure CLI commands, but it has blown up with all of the formatting and conversions I had to make-- so it may make sense now to break this into a script file and multiple lines. It honestly is pretty easy to follow in VS code with the syntax highlighting (which doesn't really occur here) and its more so been the documentation and understanding what modules exist for Powershell.

Comment: Can you add the incorrect output you're seeing as well. If I run your code locally it's helpful if I can make sure I can reproduce the issue otherwise I might end up investigating the wrong thing :-)

Comment: Check your Json. UsedCapacity is not an int, it is an array of object. Thus, change your statement from ` $_.UsedCapacity / 1024` to ` $_.UsedCapacity[0] / 1024`

Comment: There's a mismatch between the output from ```az monitor metrics list``` and what ```format-table``` is trying to do. The ```az``` command is returning properties as *arrays* in the json - i.e. ```{ "Id": [...], "ResourceGroup": [...], "UsedCapacity": [...]``` so your ```format-table``` expression is trying to calculate ```@( 1442090.0 ) / 1024``` instead of ```1442090.0 / 1024```. ```Format-Table``` is swallowing an exception generated by the former, and showing an empty / null value instead.

Comment: You *might* be able to fix it by altering your ```--query "{Id:value[].id,...``` to return an object with single value properties rather than arrays, or you could do what @SagePourpre suggests and extract values from the arrays inside your ```Format-Table``` expressions instead. I'd steer toward trying to fix the query tbh, but either approach should fix the issue.

Comment: @SagePourpre @mclayton - You were both correct, shows what new eyes can do when looking at something for too long. haha 
The fix (with my label) `{([int]$_.UsedCapacity[0]/1024).ToString()+" GiB"}`
Sage was first and technically right, but I think mclayton hit it on the head.

Comment: Np. Btw, Powershell has built in “multiplier suffixes” for kb, mb, gb etc - for example ```$x = 10mb```, so your expression could become ```{([int]$_.UsedCapacity[0]/ 1kb ).ToString()+" GiB"}```. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_numeric_literals?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: Thanks @mclayton, I stumbled across those, but they don't have GiB (1000 vs 1024), so I stuck with 1024. All of the tips and feedback has been very helpful for me and I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What was I doing wrong?**

The response from the az CLI commands contains arrays that I was not referencing properly. I was trying to use the array as an int directly.

**How was it fixed?**

I referenced the first element and then proceeded with my division.

```
    @{Label="Gibibytes";
      Expression={If(($_.UsedCapacity -eq $null) 
                 -or ($_.UsedCapacity -eq 0)){0} 
                  Else {([int]$_.UsedCapacity[0]/1.074e+9).ToString()+" GiB"}}}
```

**How was it solved?**

Thanks to @SagePourpre for pointing out that I was getting an array of object, not an actual int returned:

> "Check your Json. UsedCapacity is not an int, it is an array of object. Thus, change your statement from  `$_.UsedCapacity / 1024` to  `$_.UsedCapacity[0] / 1024` –
> Sage Pourpre"

Thanks to @Mclayton for point out the above in more detail and adding that I may be able to improve the commands by adjusting my query.

> There's a mismatch between the output from az monitor metrics list and what format-table is trying to do. The az command is returning properties as arrays in the json - i.e. { "Id": [...], "ResourceGroup": [...], "UsedCapacity": [...] so your format-table expression is trying to calculate @( 1442090.0 ) / 1024 instead of 1442090.0 / 1024. Format-Table is swallowing an exception generated by the former, and showing an empty / null value instead.

Additional Tips
Microsoft has built-in type converters, but they don't seem to support Data Storage increments yet, 1000 GB vs 1024 (GiB). [Learn more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_numeric_literals?view=powershell-7.1)